# repeated Regexp in BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

we have a debate regarding the best way to use regex expression in case clause...
we need a case operation on an extracted object. 
this can be expressed in several ways.
the question is: which one will be more effective? do BQ process the regex several time if it appears in several locations?

i have adapted my code to run on the wikipedia data sample.

1st:

```
Select case when PS_Version='1' then '1st' 
            when PS_Version='2' then '2nd' 
            when PS_Version='3' then '3rd'
            else 'other' end as PS_VersionOrder
            from 
(SELECT regexp_extract(title,r'PlayStation (\d+)') as PS_Version
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] A
where title like '%PlayStation%'
limit 100)
```

2nd:

```
Select case when regexp_extract(title,r'PlayStation (\d+)')='1' then '1st' 
            when regexp_extract(title,r'PlayStation (\d+)')='2' then '2nd' 
            when regexp_extract(title,r'PlayStation (\d+)')='3' then '3rd'
            else 'other' end as PS_VersionOrder
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] A
where title like '%PlayStation%'
limit 100
```

the regex people claim the 1st will be more efficient. the DB man prefer the 2nd one as it does not involve subqueries...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd agree with what Alex said, but I'll add that the first query is also going to be better from an execution standpoint. BigQuery does subqueries very efficiently, but may not do the common subexpression elimination in the case clause (it might, however, but you shouldn't rely on it).

Answer (score 2):

IMO, I would choose the **1st**.

### Why ?

#### 1. Maintenance

Although the 2nd doesn't contain subqueries, it **duplicates** the regex. If you decide to change this regex later, it makes the maintenance more difficult.

#### 2. Readability

The 2nd is less readable. You must read *long* redundant case statements before understand the code.

#### 3. User experience

The 2nd and the 1st may defer in performance. You should measure time needed to perform the two queries. Then check if the difference in time, if it exists, has a **noticeable** impact on your final user experience.

- If the 2nd beats the 1st with 100 ms for instance, a human won't notice it.
- If the query is involved in a nightly batch, use the 1st approach.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I would like to better understand how does the BQ engine process these? does it process the regex only once (as some other DB engines would do) or does it repeat it several times if it is expressed several times.

Comment: My answer is quite agnostic. I can't say how BQ engine process this. However, you can either search elsewhere (forums, google, BQ documentation...) or try both queries and determine which one is better in terms of memory consumption, speed of code etc